# Multiple Ultrasonic Sensors with Arduino and 74HC595 Shift Register

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I'm currently developing a project aimed at streamlining the process of identifying available closets within my school lockers room. The objective is to utilize ultrasonic sensors to determine the occupancy status of each closet, ensuring that students can easily locate an unoccupied one without searching through each door. For testing purposes, I'm using an Arduino along with just 8 ultrasonic sensors and one 74HC595 shift register. The final implementation will involve an ESP32, expanding the system to cover approximately 48 closets, each equipped with its own ultrasonic sensor and LED indicator.

I searched about the 74HC595 shift register and tried to implement my own testing code.

- the functionality i've aimed to implement:

This Arduino code is designed to interface multiple HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensors with an Arduino using a 74HC595 shift register. The shift register is utilized to control the VCC (power) of each ultrasonic sensor individually. The wiring involves connecting the echo pins of all sensors together and connecting them to a single Arduino pin (EchoPin). Similarly, the trigger pins of all sensors are connected together and linked to another Arduino pin (TrigPin). The ground pins of all sensors are connected to a common ground pin on the Arduino.

Upon pressing a button connected to pin A0, the Arduino initiates a distance measurement sequence. The 74HC595 shift register is used to selectively provide power to each ultrasonic sensor one at a time. This is achieved by shifting a binary value corresponding to a specific sensor's power pin into the shift register and updating the latch pin to activate the chosen sensor. The distance readings from each sensor are then obtained and stored in an array (sensorsValue).

The getDistance function calculates the distance using the HC-SR04 sensor's echo and trigger pins, based on the time it takes for the ultrasonic pulse to travel to the target and back.

Overall, this code enables efficient control and reading of multiple ultrasonic sensors through a single Arduino, optimizing power consumption by activating sensors selectively. The serial monitor outputs the distance readings for each sensor when the button is pressed.

- my code :

```cpp
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                                                        :::      ::::::::   */
/*   Shifter.ino                                        :+:      :+:    :+:   */
/*                                                    +:+ +:+         +:+     */
/*   By: unknown <unknown@student.1337.ma>        +#+  +:+       +#+        */
/*                                                +#+#+#+#+#+   +#+           */
/*   Created: 2024/02/28 21:26:13 by unknown          #+#    #+#             */
/*   Updated: 2024/02/28 22:55:14 by unknown         ###   ########.fr       */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/

/*

   Trigger HC-SR04 units with a 74HC595

   Wiring :

    Arduino pin 2 to echo of all HCSR04
    Arduino pin 3 to trig of all HCSR04
    Arduino Ground pin to GND of all HCSR04

    74HC595 ` POWER ` pin (16) to vcc of the Arduino (5v)
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 1 ` pin (15) to VCC of the first HCSR04
    74HC595 ` SERIAL INPUT ` pin (14) to Arduino pin (6)
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT ENABLE ` pin (13) to Arduino (GND)
    74HC595 ` REGISTER CLOCK / LATCH ` pin (12) to Arduino pin (7)
    74HC595 ` SHIFT REGISTER CLOCK ` pin (11) to Arduino (8)
    74HC595 ` SHIFT REGISTER CLEAR ` pin (10) to Arduino GND
    74HC595 pin (9) NOT USED

    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 2 ` pin (1) to VCC of the second HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 3 ` pin (2) to VCC of the third HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 4 ` pin (3) to VCC of the fourth HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 5 ` pin (4) to VCC of the fifth HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 6 ` pin (5) to VCC of the sixth HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 7 ` pin (6) to VCC of the seventh HCSR04
    74HC595 ` OUTPUT 8 ` pin (7) to VCC of the eighth HCSR04
    74HC595 ` Ground ` pin (8) to vcc of the Arduino (GND)
*/



/*When Clicking the button, Arduino will read the value of
  each sensor value continuously (the first sensor, then the second , ...) and store it in  the sensors_value double array*/
int btn_trigger = A0;

// HCSR04 echo && trig pins
const int EchoPin = 2;
const int TrigPin = 3;

// Binary pin values for shift register
const int sensorsPin[8] = {
  B00000001,  /*1*/
  B00000010, /*2*/
  B00000100, /*4*/
  B00001000, /*8*/
  B00010000, /*16*/
  B00100000, /*32*/
  B01000000, /*64*/
  B10000000 /*128*/
};

double sensorsValue[8] = {
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
  0.00,
};

// Pin connected to ST_CP of 74HC595
const int latchPin = 7;

// Pin connected to DS of 74HC595
const int dataPin = 6;

// Pin connected to SH_CP of 74HC595
const int clockPin = 8;

// Pin connected to MR (SRCLR) of 74HC595 (active low)
const int clearPin = 9;

double getDistance(int triggerPin, int echoPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("HCSR04BitShiftV1 Initialization...");

  pinMode(btn_trigger, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(TrigPin, OUTPUT);

  // Set pinMode for 74HC595 pins
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);

  // Additional pin for clearing the shift register
  pinMode(clearPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(clearPin, LOW);  // Clear the shift register initially
}

void loop() {
  // Check if the button is pressed
  int buttonState = digitalRead(btn_trigger);

  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Getting Distance ...");
    // Iterate through each sensor
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      // Set the latchPin LOW before sending data
      digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);

      // Shift out the binary value for the current sensor
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, sensorsPin[i]);

      Serial.print("Shifted Value: ");
      Serial.println(sensorsPin[i], BIN);

      // Set the latchPin HIGH to update the shift register
      digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

      // Get the distance for the current sensor and store it in the array
      sensorsValue[i] = getDistance(TrigPin, EchoPin);

      // Print the distance for debugging
      Serial.print("Sensor ");
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(sensorsValue[i]);
      Serial.println("cm");
      // Delay between sensor readings
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}

/*Get the Distance value*/
double getDistance(int triggerPin, int echoPin)
{
  unsigned long duration = 0;
  double distance = 0.0;
  float soundspead = 0.034;

  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW); // Clear the trigger
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigger pin to HIGH state for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  // Reads the echo pin, and returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  Serial.print("Pulse Duration: ");
  Serial.print(duration);
  Serial.println(" microseconds");

  distance = (soundspead * duration) / 2;
  return distance;
}
```

- Wiring :

[image: my testing schematics]

- Problem :

But I've encountered a big problem which is that the pulse duration readings for all ultrasonic sensors consistently show 0 microseconds, resulting in distance readings of 0.00 cm. This suggests that the pulseIn function, responsible for measuring the duration of the echo signal, is not receiving valid signals or is not functioning as expected. I suspect potential problems in the wiring, shared echo, and trigger pin configurations, as well as issues with the timing of trigger signals, echo signal reception, and the overall configuration of the 74HC595 shift register.

- Output :

```
HCSR04BitShiftV1 Initialization...
Getting Distance ...
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 1: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 2: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 3: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 4: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 5: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 6: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 7: 0.00cm
Pulse Duration: 0 microseconds
Sensor 8: 0.00cm
```

- Clarification :

I apologize for any confusion caused by my initial message. To clarify, in my first attempt, I inadvertently connected the ultrasonic sensor's trig pin directly to the output of the shift register, rather than controlling the power of each sensor individually. Additionally, I used separate pins on the Arduino for each sensor's echo pin. While this configuration did work, it resulted in the utilization of a significant number of pins . That's why I thought using shift register to control sensors would be a better approach.

Initially, I attempted to control four ultrasonic sensors by connecting their trig pins directly to the output of the shift register. Here is the link to the corresponding [Tinkercad project](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/35OOmRfpQJs-ultrasonic-distance-sensing-with-shift-registers/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard%3Fcollection%3Ddesigns%26type%3Dcircuits&sharecode=_WTT3Y3u6X5gkH5PY6UbP6dCHOSni9hURti0_H86PB0)!

In my second attempt, I explored a different approach by connecting the VCC of all sensors to the outputs of the shift register for control, aiming to minimize the number of pins used. You can view the project on Tinkercad via the following [link](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4VS2loCt9BO-shifter/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard%3Fcollection%3Ddesigns%26type%3Dcircuits&sharecode=BCOL5jWmQpCFJMlmZkSDTaiuxuDvl_GYz6KLmYQfPEY)

as I mentioned before Indeed, each closet has its own ultrasonic sensor, all connected to a single ESP32. My plan involves using 6 shift registers, each controlling 8 ultrasonic sensors with one 74HC595, thereby minimizing the number of pins used to 2 main pins shared among all shift registers and six separate control pins (one for each shift register). While using 48 ultrasonic may seem excessive and complex, that's the task I've been assigned. However, I'm exploring whether it's feasible or if alternative sensor options would be more suitable in terms of cost and functionality.

I would be extremely grateful for your guidance. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concept. You're triggering all sensors with just one pin and also expect the echo on a single pin, the shift register only controls which sensor has "power". Unfortunately, a sensor that does not have power may still interfere with your measurement, as the resistance of the output lines to ground is not infinite. Also, I doubt that the shift register can provide enough power on its outputs to drive the sensors.

Comment: Any particular reason you use ultrasonic sensors? Wouldn't a simple LED sensor barrier be easier?

Comment: The 74HC595 datasheet claims 6mA output current. [This guide](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/complete-guide-for-ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/) states a working current for the typical HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor module as 15mA, which is - in fact - higher than 6mA. So I would second PMF here. And also you probably need to isolate each echo pin somewhat with a diode. Depends on if the echo pin gets actively driven in each state.

Comment: why do you have eight ultrasonic sensors, when the final product will have only one?

Comment: @jsotola I think the OP means that "each [of the 48 closets] has it's own ultrasonic sensor", but all connected to a single ESP32.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for your response and insights. I apologize for any confusion caused by my initial message. To clarify, in my first attempt, I inadvertently connected the ultrasonic sensor's trig pin directly to the output of the shift register, rather than controlling the power of each sensor individually. Additionally, I used separate pins on the Arduino for each sensor's echo pin. While this configuration did work, it resulted in the utilization of a significant number of pins . That's why I thought using shift register to control sensors would be a better approach.

Comment: @PMF Initially, I attempted to control four ultrasonic sensors by connecting their trig pins directly to the output of the shift register. Here is the link to the corresponding Tinkercad project: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/35OOmRfpQJs-ultrasonic-distance-sensing-with-shift-registers/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard%3Fcollection%3Ddesigns%26type%3Dcircuits&sharecode=_WTT3Y3u6X5gkH5PY6UbP6dCHOSni9hURti0_H86PB0

Comment: @PMF In my second attempt, I explored a different approach by connecting the VCC of all sensors to the outputs of the shift register for control, aiming to minimize the number of pins used. You can view the project on Tinkercad via the following link:
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4VS2loCt9BO-shifter/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard%3Fcollection%3Ddesigns%26type%3Dcircuits&sharecode=BCOL5jWmQpCFJMlmZkSDTaiuxuDvl_GYz6KLmYQfPEY

Comment: @PMF as u mentioned to jsotola Indeed, each closet has its own ultrasonic sensor, all connected to a single ESP32. My plan involves using 6 shift registers, each controlling 8 ultrasonic sensors with one 74HC595, thereby minimizing the number of pins used to 2 main pins shared among all shift registers and six separate control pins (one for each shift register). While using 48 ultrasonic may seem excessive and complex, that's the task I've been assigned. However, I'm exploring whether it's feasible or if alternative sensor options would be more suitable in terms of cost and functionality.

Comment: If connecting the echo pins to individual input pins works, that could be a possible solution. You could use an Arduino Due instead of an ESP32 - it's a bit more expensive but has more than 50 input pins.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for suggesting the Arduino Due as an alternative to the ESP32. However, purchasing an Arduino Due in my country's electronic stores is quite expensive. I'm still exploring options to use ultrasonic sensors with a shift register while minimizing the number of pins used as much as possible. In my opinion, it might be more efficient to consider using alternative sensor types with the shift register instead of ultrasonic sensors. Do you have any suggestions for alternative sensors that could be used in this setup?

Comment: One possible alternative I already mentioned above was a LED light barrier. A led on one side and a photoresistor on the other side of the cabinet. Or they could even be on the same side if the cabinets are metallic. I use https://sensorkit.joy-it.net/de/sensors/ky-033 with some reflective tape on the other side for a similar application.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for your recommendation regarding the IR sensor or the LED and photoresistor combination as alternatives for detecting the occupancy of the cabinet. I will certainly explore the possibility of using them with my colleague. Additionally, I'm considering that while the recommended sensors you suggested are affordable, they may work just fine if they are well-positioned in the cabinet to detect the entire cabinet space.